# Is it possible to deploy a pharo image without .changes and .sources files

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I've built a pharo application that I want to give to my customers. The application is based on seaside and will run headless. For this I don't need the .source and .changes file. I would like to save some space in the distribution archive and therefor I'd like to skip those files.

At the moment it appears to me that pharo is complaining anyway if those files are missing. Is there a chance to start the image without .sources and .changes file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Sven Van Caekenberghe:

```
SmalltalkImage
        checkSourcesFileAvailability: false;
        checkChangesFileAvailability: false.
```

And then save the image.

Comment: These selectors no longer seem to exist in 6.1

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should run just fine. It should only show an error-message in the GUI but the main thread should keep running, and since you are running headless (i have made better experience with `-nodisplay` btw) your clients will not be able to see the message.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about that. I was annoyed by the dialog. But of course the web server spawns new threads for incoming requests and so it shouldn't be a problem if the UI thread is blocked.